# onActivityResult() working but it start from onCreate() Method why this Happening

Tags: android

1. **onActivityResult()** working but it start from **onCreate()** Method why this Happening

Comment: and i am initialize my all variables there

Comment: Could you please explain what is your problem and show me your code?

Comment: This happening because the caller activity was destroyed after `startActivityForResult()` was called. In that order the caller activity needs to be restore its previous state and the receive the result from the child activity.

Answer (score 1):

[onActivityResult](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onActivityResult(int,%20int,%20android.content.Intent))

```
void onActivityResult (int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
```

> Called when an activity you launched exits, giving you the requestCode
>   you started it with, the resultCode it returned, and any additional
>   data from it. The resultCode will be RESULT_CANCELED if the activity
>   explicitly returned that, didn't return any result, or crashed during
>   its operation.
>
> You will receive this call immediately before onResume() when your
>   activity is re-starting.

So it doesn't start from the onCreate(), but immediatly before the onResume().